# Is the Offline Template a static file?

Tags: templates, admin, offline

Is the Offline Template a physical .html file?

What I would like to do is write a database failure check in the config file so that if for some reason the database fails it will turn on maintenance mode which will display the offline template.

If the offline template is served from the DB this obviously will not work.

Answer (score 4):

The offline template is served from the DB, which can be edited in the control panel:

> Design > Message Pages > Offline Template

However, [Custom System Messages](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages) allows you to use custom templates as system message which can parse other template tags.

Comment: Like many other people, I wish this was built in and that you could pass templates into those files natively :(

Comment: It makes no sense to me that a template for being offline which I'd presume would be used if the database couldn't connect is indeed stored and served from the database.